# BottomSheetDialogFragment.viewBinding

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

I struggle to do a property delegate for ViewBinding on BottomSheets.

The general Idea is similar to this

For Fragments i use something like [this](https://gist.github.com/Zhuinden/ea3189198938bd16c03db628e084a4fa)

```
fun <T : ViewBinding> Fragment.viewBinding(viewBindingFactory: (View) -> T) =
FragmentViewBindingDelegate(this, viewBindingFactory)
```

On BottomSheetsDialogFragments which are Fragments it does not accept the delegate.

```
fun <T : ViewBinding> BottomSheetDialogFragment.viewBinding(viewBindingFactory: (View) -> T) =
FragmentViewBindingDelegate(this, viewBindingFactory)
```

The Lifecycle of BottomSheets would be the same as on regular Fragments, so i would not expect any problems.

Anyone came up with a solution on this ?

Answer (score 9):

You can still use the [FragmentViewBindingDelegate](https://gist.github.com/Zhuinden/ea3189198938bd16c03db628e084a4fa) and extension from Gabor.
You just also need to inflate the view inside `onCreateView()`.

For example:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment
import com.zhuinden.fragmentviewbindingdelegatekt.viewBinding


class ExampleBottomSheet : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    //Using ::bind here since the view is already inflated in onCreateView()
    private val binding by viewBinding(YourCustomViewBinding::bind)


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_view, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        //Use binding here or wherever you need it
    }
}
```

Comment: The best answer I found. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Implement ***ViewBinding*** in ***BottomSheetFragment*** like this (Works for me):

```
class CustomBottomSheet : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

private lateinit var binding: CustomBottomSheetBinding

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    binding = CustomBottomSheetBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    //onClick listener
    binding.button.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What should I do in case it's a normal DialogFragment?

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
class CampaignBottomSheet : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    private var _binding: MenuCampaignsBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        _binding = MenuCampaignsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        binding.startCampaign.setOnClickListener { println("__print::CampaignBottomSheet") }

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Unlike Fragment class, `BottomSheetDialogFragment` doesn't have a constructor that accepts layout resource. 
You can create a custom dialog for it. Basically, copy everything from `AppCompatDialogFragment` and `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.

Comment: Sounds like their need to change this in one of those jetpack releases. i wonder why that never was done so far

Comment: You can create an issue or try to reach one of jetpack developers here or on reddit https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460964&template=1182267

Comment: `BottomSheetDialogFragment` isn't part of Jetpack - it is part of the Material Design Components. You'd want to file an issue against them.

Comment: @ianhanniballake right, but it extends AppCompatDialogFragment which doesn't expose the constructor with layout res. Please add it in future updates.

Comment: I believe its googles part to just do it. I was not aware of Jetpack or MDC. Wasn't the mission to ease development ?

Comment: @Kitesurfer I turned to Ian Lake, he works in google.